# Is there a way to move a local wordpress installation on ubuntu to windows 10 after a clean install

Tags: lamp, xampp, wordpress

By clean install, I mean after wiping ubuntu and installing windows 10. I've moved all the lampp files to a flash drive but I'm not sure if it will work on windows. Any help will be appreciated